# Tensorflow lite retrained model : Android application crashes after replacing my model

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am following this tensorflow light tutorial :https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#5

Android application provided [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2)

Works fine when I install and run on android mobile. But when I replaced newly created flower model it always crashes. Here are the logs:

```
05-31 22:55:46.492 581-581/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-31 22:55:47.484 581-581/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo D/TfLiteCameraDemo: Created a Tensorflow Lite Image Classifier.
05-31 22:55:47.496 581-598/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-31 22:55:47.657 581-598/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (Ifd751822f5)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
    Build Date: 01/26/16 Tue
    Local Branch: AU12_SBA
    Remote Branch: 
    Local Patches: 
    Reconstruct Branch: 
05-31 22:55:47.664 581-598/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-31 22:55:47.892 581-581/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
05-31 22:55:48.010 581-581/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo I/CameraManager: Using legacy camera HAL.
05-31 22:55:48.395 581-597/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state CONFIGURING
05-31 22:55:48.395 581-648/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo I/RequestThread-0: Configure outputs: 1 surfaces configured.
05-31 22:55:48.395 581-648/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo D/Camera: app passed NULL surface
05-31 22:55:48.469 581-581/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo I/Choreographer: Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-31 22:55:48.555 581-597/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
05-31 22:55:48.633 581-597/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo D/TfLiteCameraDemo: Timecost to put values into ByteBuffer: 41
05-31 22:55:48.801 581-597/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo D/TfLiteCameraDemo: Timecost to run model inference: 169
05-31 22:55:48.853 581-597/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo D/TfLiteCameraDemo: Timecost to put values into ByteBuffer: 43
05-31 22:55:48.985 581-597/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo D/TfLiteCameraDemo: Timecost to run model inference: 133
05-31 22:55:48.987 581-597/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo I/RequestQueue: Repeating capture request set.
05-31 22:55:48.993 581-648/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
    Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
    Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
05-31 22:55:49.033 581-597/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo D/TfLiteCameraDemo: Timecost to put values into ByteBuffer: 40
05-31 22:55:49.159 581-597/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo D/TfLiteCameraDemo: Timecost to run model inference: 126
05-31 22:55:49.212 581-597/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo D/TfLiteCameraDemo: Timecost to put values into ByteBuffer: 42
05-31 22:55:49.332 581-597/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo D/TfLiteCameraDemo: Timecost to run model inference: 121
05-31 22:55:49.385 581-597/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo D/TfLiteCameraDemo: Timecost to put values into ByteBuffer: 46
05-31 22:55:49.545 581-597/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo A/libc: Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1, fault addr 0xb946ac98 in tid 597 (CameraBackgroun)
```

It will be great if some can provide any input regarding this

Thanks for looking into issue and sorry about late reply. Here are the steps I followed :
1. Retrained the model using this tutorial : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#3

Command to create model :

```
python -m scripts.retrain   
--bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks   
--how_many_training_steps=500   
--model_dir=tf_files/models/   
--summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}"   
--output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb   
--output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt   
--architecture="${ARCHITECTURE}"   
--image_dir=/home/ganesh/Documents/Developement/MachineLearning/new_approach/flower_photos_subset
```

Here image size I used is :- 224 and architecture:mobilenet_0.50_224

I tested the retrained model and it is working great using command:

```
python -m scripts.label_image \
--graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb  \
--image=/home/ganesh/Documents/Developement/MachineLearning/new_approach/flower_images/flower.jpeg
```

It gives correct result
Then I converted it into Tensorflow lite model using :

```
toco \
--input_file=/tmp/output_graph.pb \
--output_file=/tmp/graph.lite \
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--output_format=TFLITE \
--input_shape=1,224,224,3 \
--input_array=input \
--output_array=final_result \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--input_data_type=FLOAT
```

Files got generated successfully
But when I replaced same in the android application, It is getting crashed
**As I am able to test the the retrained model using command and it is giving the correct results, I feel there is problem in converting it into lite format(For Android)**

Comment: "Works fine when I install and run on android mobile." -> what is the original model used in the app when it is working? Are the input and output types and shapes the same as the new model?

Comment: @PannagSanketi I have updated the details, please let me know in case you need any other details

Comment: Thanks. I think I have found the issue. PTAL at my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are converting the TF model to a `float` tflite model via `toco --input_data_type=FLOAT` whereas the [tflite poets 2 app](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/android/tflite/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tflitecamerademo/ImageClassifier.java#L184) feeds `ByteBuffer` input to the model (it converts the image `Bitmap` to a `ByteBuffer`). Originally it used a *quantized* mobilenet tflite model which was expecting a `Byte` input. However, when you replaced that with your model, the model started expecting `float` but the app fed it `Byte`. Thus it crashed.

The other application that you mentioned [TFMobile poets 2 app](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/android/tfmobile/src/org/tensorflow/demo/TensorFlowImageClassifier.java#L135) works correctly since it converts the bitmaps to `float[]` rather than a `ByteBuffer`.

So if you want to go back to your first application, you can quantize your retrained graph first in tensorflow and then tell `toco` as well that your input is `quantized` (see [toco commandline examples here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/cmdline_examples.md#graphdef-quant)) and then try it out again.

(This [script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/quantization/quantize_graph.py) is from the TensorFlow repository, but it is not included in the default installation).

```
python -m scripts.quantize_graph \
--input=tf_files/optimized_graph.pb \
--output=tf_files/rounded_graph.pb \
--output_node_names=final_result \
--mode=weights_rounded
```

> However, note that quantizing the graph post training might result in a loss of accuracy. So definitely measure that. Another option is to insert fake quantization ops into the graph during training before converting to a quantized graph. That will ensure less loss of accuracy, but that is a lot more work.

Answer (score 0):

I created custom model in same way and this time I tried with different android application (TFMobile), it worked :) Here is the tutorial link :[here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/#7)